# get returned value of promise with $q.all

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I would like to get the returned value of promises using the `$q.all()` method.
This is what I've tried so far.

```
var promise1 = function(time){
            var defered = $q.defer();
            var promise = defered.promise;

            defered.resolve(time);
            console.log(time);
            return promise;
          };

 var promise2 = function(time){
            var defered = $q.defer();
            var promise = defered.promise;

            defered.resolve(time);
            console.log(time);
            return promise;
          };
```

And the way I'm trying to get both `time` returned from `promise1` and `promise2`

```
$q.all([promise1,promise2]).then(function(){
              console.log("Worked");
              console.log(promise1 + " , " + promise2);
              //ref.close();
            });
```

But the console prints the whole function of the promises, like this.

```
function (time){
            var defered = $q.defer();
            var promise = defered.promise;

            defered.resolve(time);
            console.log(time);
            return promise;
          },function (time){
            var defered = $q.defer();
            var promise = defered.promise;

            defered.resolve(time);
            console.log(time);
            return promise;
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

> It's because you didn't invoke and passed a time value on your 2 functions **(promise1 and promise2)**.
>
> If you will implement it like this **[promise1, promise2]**, the $q.all will still run it but will return a function instead of a value since you have a function with parameter `function (time) {}` that wasn't filled out.

Pass a value on your promises, example: **500 (500ms)**. With this, it will work your on your **$q.all**

```
$q.all([promise1(500),promise2(500)]).then(function(data) {
   console.log("Worked");
   console.log(data);
});
```

> Since just passing **[promise1, promise2]** is like passing a raw function that waits till the caller invokes them internally in another function e.g promise1(), promise2()

**Sample Scenario:**

```
var add = function (x, y) { return x + y; }

console.log(add);        // ƒ (x, y) { return x + y; }

console.log(add(1, 2));  // 3
```

Comment: I get that, but the thing is that I called `promise1` and `promise2` inside 2 events passing the params, so I thougth when those 2 were fired, the `$q.all()` would fire aswell.

Comment: @JaimeCuellar you need to declare a data param inside the .then function to fetch its results:
$q.all([promise1,promise2]).then(function(data){ console.log(data) }, since when you console log your promise1 and promise2, it will just console your raw functions not the data processed inside the $q.all. Just like the example above